# get blank $data params in deleteList($data) function to create delete api (in PHP apigilty) for multiple requested params

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

`deleteList($data)` function to create delete api (in PHP apigilty) for multiple requested params but I couldn't get $data params in deleteList block except blank array, please Help!

I already mentioned query parameters whitelist.

API url :

http://192.168.1.210/xyz-development/saif/public/api/fileupload/36?id=36&filename=13246685.png&delete_type=test

Answer (score 0):

`deleteList($data)` in `Resource` Controller is purposed to handle `DELETE` HTTP Method. And `$data` itself come from `Body Request`, not from `URL Query Params`.

If you wanna retrieve data from `URL Query Params` you can retrieve it manually from `$this->getEvent()->getRequest()->getQuery()` inside `Resource` Controller.

*Example:*

```
$id = $this->getEvent()->getRequest()->getQuery("id");
$filename   = $this->getEvent()->getRequest()->getQuery("filename");
$deleteType = $this->getEvent()->getRequest()->getQuery("delete_type")
```